# Installing Ruby 1.9.3 on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I have ruby 1.9.2p320 installed on my Mac and I tried to update it but don't know how so I used *rvm* to install ruby 1.9.3 and once that had finished installing, after typing `ruby -v` I still get ruby 1.9.2p320.

### Update

I now have ruby 1.9.3 installed thanks to **Simone Carletti**!

Comment: Please open two separate questions if you have two issues. Otherwise you get mixed answers and you makes it harder to accept a single response.

Comment: You're right. I've fixed it now and accepted your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install a Ruby version with RVM

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

then to switch to it

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3
```

The latter command is probably the one you forgot to execute.

You might want to configure an [.rvmrc](https://rvm.io//workflow/rvmrc/) file for your project in order to remember the settings.

About the other issue, you should open a separate question.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to execute it. That's alright now, I think. I'm using `ruby 1.9.3p194`. That's correct, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can also install use **rbenv** to install and manage different versions of Ruby.

**Note:** I don't have anything against rvm. I simply noticed that installing various Rubies is a constant source of questions, both in Stack Overflow and also at work!

**Requirements**

- Here I'm assuming that you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). (If you haven't installed that yet, make sure your permissions are correct on `/usr/local/` after installation is complete, or you can run into mysterious-looking errors that should not be preventing you from installing Ruby.)
- Run `rvm implode` before installing rbenv. This will destroy rvm.

**To install rbenv using Homebrew**

1. Update Homebrew.

   ```
    $ brew update
   ```
2. Install rbenv.

   ```
    $ brew install rbenv
   ```
3. Install ruby-build.

   ```
    $ brew install ruby-build
   ```
4. Follow the instructions listed after installing these formulae in order to make it available correctly in your shell.

**To install Ruby 1.9.3**

1. See what versions of Ruby you can install.

   ```
    $ rbenv install
   ```
2. Install one. The lastest as of this post is `1.9.3-p194`.

   ```
    $ rbenv install 1.9.3-p194
   ```

**To use Ruby 1.9.3**

```
$ rbenv global 1.9.3-p194
```

**To rehash rbenv**

Sometimes you need to run `rbenv rehash`, like when you install a gem that has native extensions for your operating system.

```
$ rbenv rehash
```

There are lots of other things you can do with rbenv, like use a particular Ruby in a particular directory, or a particular ruby in the shell. See the appropriate docs for more info!